# Azure Function execution latencies

Tags: azure-functions

I am currently facing an issue with Azure Function calls.

When I call the AF for the first time (after long time of no use), it starts the execution of the code almost instantanelly. But if I call the same function a few seconds after it has finished, it takes 10-15sec, between the moment it starts and the moments it executes the code. (Each time I repeat the operation the result stay the same : 1 call - very quick, all other calls : latencies).

```
[FunctionName("GetUserDestinationsList")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(Settings.DefaultAuthorization, "get", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    try
    {
        log.Info($"Start Execute function");
        var allDestinations = await DestinationsFactory.GetAllDestinations();
        IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> values = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs();
        ...
}
```

I log the start of the code execution.
Here the result of the calls :

> - First Call of the Function :
>
> 2018-11-22 08:24:30.517 - Function started (Id=c86f9b71-03ed-...)
>
> 2018-11-22 08:24:30.955 - Start Execute function
>
> 2018-11-22 08:24:39.600 - Function completed (Success, Id=c86f9b71-03ed-..., Duration=9062ms)
>
> - Second Call :
>
> 2018-11-22 08:24:44.482 - Function started (Id=12eb3f0e-a180-...)
>
> 2018-11-22 08:24:53.489 - Start Execute function
>
> 2018-11-22 08:24:58.534 - Function completed (Success, Id=12eb3f0e-a180-..., Duration=14047ms)
>
> - Third Call :
>
> 2018-11-22 08:25:04.479 - Function started (Id=30784cc2-d2de-...)
>
> 2018-11-22 08:25:17.985 - Start Execute function
>
> 2018-11-22 08:25:22.856 - Function completed (Success, Id=30784cc2-d2de-..., Duration=18381ms)

As you can see, there is some latencies on the second and third call.

Three calls takes sames parameters and return the same result at the end, only the begining takes more or less time.

I can also reproduce this problem locally.

Any idea ?

**EDIT :**
If I wait about 20 sec between each call, there is no more latencies. They seems to occur only when calls are close to each other.

Comment: What runtime version are you using?

Comment: The function was initialized on V1 runtime